# Minimum number of channels in hub-spoke in WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, series

In a WebSphere MQ environment where five queue managers are in a hub-and-spoke configuration
how many channels must be created in order for the four spoke queue managers to exchange messages with the one hub queue manager hub-and-spoke configuration?

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include all the queue managers in a WMQ cluster, you will need to define 
1. on the hub:
a.  CLUSRCVR channel pointing to itself
2. on each of the 4 spokes:
a.  CLUSRCVR channel pointing to itself
b.  CLUSSDR channel pointing to the hub queue manager; same name as the hub's CLUSRCVR channel

The hub qmgr should be designated as the REPOS for the cluster.

See document http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzah.doc/qc10120_.htm in the WMQ V7.0 InfoCenter for complete instructions on setting up a cluster.